# Can't use activity table in join query for update

Tags: activities, mysql

In our set-up we have custom fields associated to activities, the value of which is computed periodically by scheduled job. The job executes a query that reads something like:

`UPDATE civicrm_value_something sth
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      a.id, someexpression() as value
    FROM civicrm_activity a
    JOIN sometables
    WHERE somecondition
  ) r ON r.id = sth.entity_id
SET sth.somefield = r.value;`

This was working fine until today when we migrated from 4.7.24 to 4.7.30, which introduces some new triggers on `civicrm_activity` table. The problem is that [MySQL does not support executing triggers that update a table used (even just for read) in the statement that cause the trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). So the query fails with this error:

> [nativecode=1442 ** Can't update table 'civicrm_activity' in stored function/trigger 
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.]

The only solution I can see is to split the query and store the result of the sub-query in a temporary table. This is not desirable because it is less convenient, less performant (if the subquery fits in memory) and less atomic.

Has someone faced a similar problem and come up with a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to disable the trigger, run your upgrade and re-create it at the end.